# How to get client value in BeforeSave or BeforeUpdate hooks

Tags: go, hook, go-gorm

Initial value of user in database is:

```
user := User{Name: "Ketamplok", Age: 18, Active: false}
```

And I want to update it with this:

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "Kecopret", Age: 20, Active: true})
```

then I want to get the value of Age which is 20 inside either these hooks:

```
func (u *User) BeforeSave(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    fmt.Println(u.Age) // this shows 18 instead of 20
    return
}

func (u *User) BeforeUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    fmt.Println(u.Age) // this shows 18 instead of 20
    return
}
```

But I couldn't get the value, instead what I got is the old one which is 18

How can I get the "to be saved" value? the new one? the 20?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You should use the parameter `tx *gorm.DB` from your function. Try something like this:

```
func (u *User) BeforeSave(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    for column, value := range tx.Statement.Dest {
        fmt.Println(column, "value is", string(value))
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Transaction

Comment: thanks Nikita Petromax, eventhough your answer is not 100% solution to me problem but you give me a clue though, btw your last name is similar to one of a fuel/gas names in me country.

Comment: :-D I'm glad to help!

Comment: could ou mark my answer as accepted, please?

Comment: tx.Statement.Dest is an interface{} type thus cannot be looped how do you somehow manage to loop over it?